# C# iTextSharp multi fonts in a single cell

Tags: c#, itext

First off I'm not that great with C# and it's been a while since I've worked with it..

I'm making a windows form for a friend that delivers packages. So I want to transfer his current paper form, into a .pdf with the library iTextSharp. He still needs to print the form to get the customer signature and so on.

**What I need:**
I want the table to have a little headline, "Company name" for example, the text should be a little smaller than the text input from the windows form(richTextBox1)

Currently I'm using cells and was wondering if I can use 2 different font sizes within the same cell?

**What I have:**

```
table.AddCell("Static headline" + Chunk.NEWLINE + richTextBox1.Text);
```

**What I "want":**

```
var normalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 9);

var boldFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);

table.AddCell("Static headline", boldFont + Chunk.NEWLINE + richTextBox1.Text, normalFont);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're passing a `String` and a `Font` to the `AddCell()` method. That's not going to work. You need the `AddCell()` method that takes a `Phrase` object or a `PdfPCell` object as parameter.

A `Phrase` is an object that consists of different `Chunk`s, and the different `Chunk`s can have different font sizes. Please read [chapter 2 of my book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf) for more info about this object.

```
Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.Add(
    new Chunk("Some BOLD text",  new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLD))
);
phrase.Add(new Chunk(", some normal text", new Font()));
table.AddCell(phrase);
```

A `PdfPCell` is an object to which you can add different objects, such as `Phrase`s, `Paragraph`s, `Image`s,...

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.AddElement(new Paragraph("Hello"));
cell.AddElement(list);
cell.AddElement(image);
```

In this snippet `list` is of type `List` and `image` is of type `Image`.

The first snippet uses **text mode**; the second snippet uses **composite mode**. Cells behave very differently depending on the mode you use.

This is all explained in the [documentation](http://itextpdf.com/book); you can find hundreds of C# examples [here](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/178).